# Which is better in MySQL, an IFNULL or OR logic

Tags: mysql

I have added `deleted` columns to lots of tables and I have a query that LEFT JOINs across 9 tables and want to checked the `deleted` column for each of the tables.

I made the deleted column a TINYINT rather than a BIT for some flexibility in terms of more than one "deleted" value for workflow reasons.  I want NULL *or* zero to mean "not deleted" and any other non-null, non-zero value to mean "deleted". I can see two approaches in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (k.deleted IS NULL OR k.deleted = 0) 
   AND (c.deleted IS NULL OR c.deleted = 0)
   ...
```

Or alternatively

```
WHERE IFNULL(k.deleted,0) = 0
   AND IFNULL(c.deleted,0) = 0
   ...
```

Efficiency matters a lot in this query as it is a 9 table LEFT JOIN that returns zero or one record and it runs a *lot* so I really need maximum efficiency.  I think the `IFNULL` looks more elegant, but I have a nagging feeling that MySQL might optimize queries with functions differently than AND / OR logic in WHERE clauses.  Unless I hear otherwise, I am going with the more verbose "OR" form just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both going to be pretty bad, because both preclude indexes.  One suggestion is to default the value so it is `0` instead of `NULL`.  That will at least make the `WHERE` clause able to use indexes.  This query is much more optimal because it can use indexes:

```
WHERE k.deleted = 0 AND c.deleted = 0
```

For clarity, I would use the ANSI standard `COALESCE()` rather than `IFNULL()`.  And my personal preference is for the `OR`, because I think it is clearer.

Comment: The good news is that all of my 9 JOINs use integer unique primary keys for the ON clause so the "deleted" check can be later in the optimization and be low additional cost.   I will take your advice and set the `DEFAULT` to 0 in the data model and then use the `WHERE` clause as you suggest above to make it a bit more efficient.  Also I want to model good practice implementing booleans in this data model that I also use for teaching.